# JMX runtime input lookup class is not available because this JRE does not support JMX

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, jmx

I am getting the above error when I try running my application. I am sure it has something to do with my updating from log4j to log4j2 since if I do not reference my log4j2.xml file the error is gone.

Why am I getting this error?

Here is the full stack trace, if it helps:

```
2016-09-12 12:01:26,124 main WARN JMX runtime input lookup class is not available because this JRE does not support JMX. JMX lookups will not be available, continuing configuration. java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JmxRuntimeInputArgumentsLookup to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newCheckedInstanceOf(LoaderUtil.java:168)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Loader.newCheckedInstanceOf(Loader.java:301)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:106)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder.build(PatternLayout.java:492)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout(PatternLayout.java:376)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Builder.<init>(ConsoleAppender.java:168)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.newBuilder(ConsoleAppender.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.createBuilder(PluginBuilder.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:119)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:566)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:582)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger$PrivateManager.getContext(Logger.java:59)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:914)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.<clinit>(JspServlet.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Dev
```

Mode.main(DevMode.java:311)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a warning, not a real error. It does not indicate there is a real problem.

I agree that showing the stack trace in this case is unnecessary and confusing. I raised [ticket LOG4J2-1582](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1582) for this on the Log4j 2 bug tracker and fixed it.

In the next version of Log4j 2 (2.7), the stack trace will no longer show, just the warning message.

Comment: Ok thank you. Until the next version comes out, is there any way that I can ignore this warning for all of the machines I am running on, without specifying it in Eclipse?